# Django ajax file upload problem csrf

Tags: ajax, django, file, upload, csrf

I'm trying to do a ajax file upload using django. I am trying to make this example work

http://www.johnberns.com/2010/07/08/using-valums-jquery-ajax-upload-with-django-1-2/

But strangely I keep getting "None" for my csrf token and even more strange is that I am doing the POST call sending the file but all I get on the server is just the following dict:

```
{u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'None']}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole premise of that linked article is wrong. You don't need to worry about the CSRF token - CSRF protection is automatically disabled for Ajax uploads, since there is no way of making it work reliably. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: I think this is no longer the case with Django's 1.2.5 security release (all requests, regardless if Ajax, require csrf): http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/feb/08/security/

Comment: @dolan: that's true. The original article is still wrong though.